# Cannot find debug info for glibc

Tags: centos, gdb, glibc, centos8

The gdb throws warning:

```
Missing separate debuginfos, use: yum debuginfo-install glibc-2.28-127.el8.x86_64
```

but the debug info cannot be found!

```sh
sudo yum debuginfo-install glibc-2.28-127.el8.x86_64

Could not find debuginfo package for the following installed packages: glibc-2.28-127.el8.x86_64
Could not find debugsource package for the following installed packages: glibc-2.28-127.el8.x86_64
```

The repo list:

```sh
yum repolist
appstream                                                                                                 
baseos                                                                                                    
debuginfo                                                                                                
extras
```

How can I fix this problem? SYSTEM INFO：CentOS8 x86_64